# Не виден след от Trail Renderer в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Хотел добавить след при передвижении объекта с помощью эффекта Trail, но его не видно в Game, но видно в Scene. Объект, к которому привязан Trial почему-то перемещается к камере и Trial оказывается ЗА камерой. Пытался переместить скриптом, не работает. Как сделать так, чтобы объект не перемещался к камере? Помогите пожалуйста!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Надо всего лишь изменить параметр Near на отрицательное значение в инспекторе камеры.